Last board with Intel ICH 8/9/10 chipsets that had both, PCI and PCIe slots and allowed to use either as main GPU
On the brink of not being retro, but:
I am trying to find the latest mainboard that

has at least two PCI slots as well as PCIe slots already (at least 1 x16 PCIe 1.0)
runs with Intel ICH 8, 9 or 10 chipsets
is able to switch the main GPU to be used either from PCI or PCIe by a setting in the BIOS.
allows running at least one SATA port as IDE
is not a server board

This seems to be a harder search than I thought.
I own an MSI P965 Neo2 board from 2007 with an ICH8 chipset. I just wondered if this board is the last with the desired configuration in the ICH series (or even overall?).

I don’t have an answer to the question in the title, but your MSI P965 Neo 2 board is not the last board meeting your requirements. Supermicro’s C2SEA motherboard, released in 2008, is a G45/ICH10 board with two PCI slots, one PCI-E Gen2 ×16 slot, one PCI-E ×4 slot, and one PCI-E ×1 slot, with support for iGPUs, PCI-E GPUs and PCI GPUs. The BIOS allows users to specify the primary display adapter: integrated graphics only, PCI then integrated, PCI-E then integrated, PCI then PCI-E, or PCI-E then PCI.
This is beyond the scope of your question, but the end of ICH didn’t signal the end of PCI GPU support or configurability: Supermicro’s later PCH-based X10SAE motherboard, released in 2012, still has two PCI slots and supports iGPUs, PCI-E GPUs and PCI GPUs. Its BIOS allows specific slots to be chosen for the primary display. The next generation of motherboards drops support for PCI display adapters.
(This isn’t supposed to be an ad for Supermicro, it’s just that they’re the manufacturer I’m most familiar with.)

That's cool. I'll update the description to narrow it down to non-server boards, though.

The motherboards I referenced aren’t server boards…

Oh, thought Supermicro is only doing that. Great answer then :-)

After I finally got on the right tracks search-wise, I found the MSI P45 Neo3-F(R) to be among the latest board meeting all requirements. It also has 4 PCI slots, even better, and PCIe 2.0.
Since it is much cheaper than the C2SEA, I'll stick with that one.

The C2SEA board allows its first SATA port to be detected as IDE, but I don’t know whether that’s enough for Windows 98. However if you install this AHCI driver you can use any AHCI port with Windows 98.

Please do not update your question by adding an answer! That is not how Stack Exchange sites work; you should know that. Instead, you should edit your question to add the additional information.

@DoxyLover this is a combined question update and answer; I suspect the OP added it as such to avoid invalidating the existing answer…

The AHCI driver linked in my comment above can be used even to install Windows (at least as long as DOS itself can boot).

No, it doesn’t happen all the time, and as DoxyLover says, when it does it’s frowned upon. In this instance, given that your new requirements (apart from price) don’t invalidate the existing answer, you should update your question and your answer accordingly. And my goal isn’t to force you to use a Supermicro board, it’s to help address your question about the latest motherboard meeting your requirements.

If you’re ever in this situation with an update to a question that does invalidate existing answers, the correct approach is to ask a new question with the refined requirements. If you’d started out saying you wanted to run Windows 98 you might have received better answers, and made the question more explicitly on-topic.
